# JAX-RS handling multiple request with same path

Tags: rest, microservices, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm developing this application in JAX-RS (rest-easy) in which i have a PUT update path

```
http://.../update/{resource_id}
```

In which you can do some requests, such as ChangeNameRequest or ChangeStyleRequest, each request is shaped in this way:

```
public class ChangeNameRequest{
    public String newName;
}

public class ChangeStyleRequest{
    public String newStyle;
}
```

And then in the controller class i have these methods:

```
@Path("/update/{id}")
@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response changeName(ChangeNameRequest request, @PathParam("id") String id)
```

and

```
@Path("/update/{id}")
@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response changeArtworkStyle(ChangeStyleRequest request, @PathParam("id") String id) {
```

The problem is that when i make a JSON request such as:

```
{
"newname" : "Name changed"
}
```

It non-deterministically chooses between one of the request handling methods so it produces an error.

How can i fix this? (Maybe i can just add a request_type field or something, but i would like to know if there are some best practices or best fixes to handle this).

Comment: why do you have the same path `@Path("/update/{id}")` on two different end points? You should probably make it something like `@Path("/name/update/{id}")` and `@Path("/artworkstyle/update/{id}")`

Comment: @Kaus2b Because (I'm still a student) in my idea there was the fact that i can update my object and the update action can be done with requests so that a single /update/ endpoint can accept different requests and do different things on this basis. Maybe i'm wrong but i can do as you said.

Comment: Two different methods cannot have the same path string. If you want to keep the same endpoint just delete one of them and on the other you can add another `@PathParam` that can be either name or artwork

Comment: Perfect, i'll create some different endpoints for each operation, Thanks :)

Comment: Hi @Kaus2b your strategy works very well, if you have it, can you cite where you found it? (it is better if i find a quote for my assignment, this is an university project).

Comment: posted a link in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/6nmq2cp1v/index.html

See the URI path examples and the section in "Extracting Request Parameters"

Comment: Thanks, you really helped me.